# Mozilla Firefox breakes html layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my page layout in the Mozilla Firefox web-browser. I use bootstrap and quite simple layout.

```
<form role="form">
<div class="...">
<button class="btn btn-block"></button>
</div>
<div class="entry-placeholder">
<input class="form-control entry" type="text" />
</div>
</form>
<div class="top-buffer-medium"></div>
<div class="dropdown">
...
</div>
<div class="...">
<div class="btn-group">
<span class="btn btn-default">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
<span class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</span>
<span class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="btn">
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block"></button>
</div>
<div class="btn">
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block"></button>
</div>
<div class="table">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
<tr ng-repeat="...">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isRowSelected" />
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></span>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

I use the default bootstrap css and no custom styles for the table. All browsers display my layout properly. And only Firefox brekes it. As you can see the table goes too far right. I thought that the problem is in the body position and tried to add

```
.body {
-webkit-position: absolute;
-khtml-position: absolute;
-moz-position: absolute;
 position: absolute;
}
```

But it didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Put the buttons in a row and the table in another row

Comment: Why all other browsers render it properly?

Comment: Proper CSS and HTML code should look the same in current FF and Chrome, or at least should not break the layout in a way you show on your screenshots. If you see something like this you should assume that you did something wrong. And a vendor prefix for `position`  does not make any sens.

Comment: Quick fix should be to add `.table { clear: left; }` to your css. Firefox handles floats differently to Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, put all your button in a row `div` and your table in a different one:

```
<form>
<div class="row">
<!-- ALL your buttons -->
</div>
<div class="row">
<!-- Your table -->
</div>
</form>
```

Also `body` style `position: absolute;` is just plain wrong.